# How to store an image after generating it (Python imaging, Plone 3)

Tags: plone

I would like to generate an image using text and a custom font. 
As it is mentioned here [Output text as GIF or PNG for use in eBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588726/output-text-as-gif-or-png-for-use-in-ebook)

How can I store the file in my content's file field?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is call the field accessor with a file-like object, preferably one that includes the file mime-type (`image/png` or `image/gif` in your case). Zope's OFS.File.File provides such info. Let's say your file field is simply called `file` (so it's setter is called `setFile`) and you have your image in a string variable named `imagedata` containing a PNG image:

```
from OFS.Image import File
image = File('ignored-id', 'ignored-title', imagedata, 'image/png')
contentobject.setFile(image)
```

Note that you may want to change your field to type [`ImageField`](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/fields/fields-reference#image_field) though; it provides a richer interface for images, including HTML tag generation and scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Get the python file-like object corresponding to the image and pass it as an argument to the field mutator method.  If the field if called `fooImage`, then the mutator, by default, is `object.setFooImage(image_file_here)`.  Or you could pass it in using the `object.update(fooImage=image_file_here)` method.